# Azure app service tenant with custom domain

Tags: azure, dns, azure-app-service-plans

I'm a little lost here and would appreciate some help:

I've set up an app service that works with:

```
tenant1.myapp.com
tenant2.myapp.com
```

etc.

I wan't to make make custom domains to work for the tenants, so that

customtenantdomain.com can point to tenant2.myapp.com

The only way I've managed to get it to work is by manually adding a custom domain "customtenantdomain.com" in the azure portal, setup A and CNAME records and from there my code handles it based on the host name. I also need to set up

```
TXT myapp.azurewebsites.net awverify
```

Is it possible to do this in another way, or at least programatically?

Ideally, I would like to only point the A-record from the domain to point to the azure IP

```
A   @   23.100.50.51
```

along with

```
TXT myapp.com awverify
```

But that does not work, obviously. Is there any reason why that should not work?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to set up mappings using powershell:

```
Get-AzureDeployment -ServiceName yourservicename | Select Url
```

Here is some more information:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-custom-domain-name